# FullTextSearch: SPSiteDataQuery on each request vs. caching data and filter in code

Tags: list, caml-query, filter, spsitedataquery

I'm implementing a full text search on list contents.

Is it more efficient to fire a SPSiteDataQuery on every request with a dynamically built CAML-Query, to filter the items?

Or is it better to fetch the data once, store it in e.g. HttpRuntime.Cache and filter the data somehow in code (maybe via DataTable.Select or something...didn't try this).

What do you think?

Comment: How much data are we talking?

Comment: about 200 - 300 items stored in 2 lists

Comment: hmm, 200-300 items in 2 lists. Do they have (multi-)lookup fields?

Comment: No. The items are in the standard pages list (PublishingPages) and a custom document library (Documents with some additional metadata). Data of the items from both lists will be displayed in one result list.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first option, as the SPSiteDataQuery already makes use of caching, if you use it correctly. It's fast as hell ;)

check my blogpost about it: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/bas/archive/2009/03/27/using-the-crosslistqueryinfo-and-crosslistquerycache.aspx

Steve peschka wrote a document on it in the past: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=95450&clcid=0x409

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx

Comment: In your blog you're talking about CrossListQueryCache. When the query changes (which does, because the CAML is created dynamically to filter the items), does it clear the cache and fetch new results? The document from Steve Peschka doesn't help because it is about SPQuery and PortalSiteMapProvider.

Comment: no, the items are cached, not the query with its items.

Comment: so then CrossListQueryCache isn't capable for a full text search. If the query changes there MUST be only the new requested items.

Comment: Is using search an option, then?!

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not an option. So I'll stick with an SPSiteDataQuery on every request.

Comment: a SPSiteDataQuery is quite performant. You can try the PortalSitemapProvider too, depending on the kind of information that you need. May i ask you why search isn't an option?

Answer (score 1):

If you want SPSiteDataQuery functionality along with caching, better to use CrossListQueryCache and CrossListQueryInfo classes.

Check here for excellent details : http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/07/17/data-access-via-caml-queries/